# How to use Python to communicate with an device connect to a different computer

Tags: python, serial-communication, communication-protocol

I have an instrument setup composed of a command-and-control computer, connected in a network with other computers which have a specific device attached to it (by device  I mean something like, for instance, a laser). The communication to these instruments is done via a Serial cable (RS-232) connected to the local computer.

```
[C&C Computer] -- [local computer] -- [device]
```

My intention is to directly control the instrument from the command-and-control. I can connect locally to the laser fine, by making use of the PySerial module. My only doubt is on how to access the instrument from the C&C Computer.